# How to map parameters with database in crystal report to show only required data

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I am confused in using parameter in Crystal Reports

I have mapped the required table and fields and design a report too. 
and created 3 parameters: BranchCode, FromDate and ToDate

Need to display all records from BranchCode During the seleted period (From & To date)

Note: So for i have designed and passed the parameter from code to crystal report.

**Now let me know how to show only the records which matching to these parameters ?**

***Note:*** I didn't use query. Just add required field from table to crystal report.

Expecting your valuable reply. 
regards, 
Sensa.

Comment: Just use these parameters in report selection formula, like {mytable.branchcode}={?param-branchcode} - you can choose fields from field explorer of course.

Comment: As in DB i have many business in each branch. And i have designed the report as Group By: Branch. Hope i have to create formula field like {mytable.branchcode}={?param-branchcode} and drag & drop the same to Branch group header - am i right?

Comment: Dear Mark Bannister, I will take a review on my older questions tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following record-selection formula:

```
{table.branch_code} = {?BranchCode}
AND {table.date_field} IN {?FromDate} TO {?ToDate}
```

Comment: Thank you. The mistake i made is: I created the required formula but not used it in the report :-(  Now i just drag the formula field in to report - its working fine.